# Blit function in python

Tags: python, function, blit

Is it posible to write a function like this in python, but without the blit function?

```
def display(self):
        x_pos = [50, screen_x-250]
        comb = zip(self.spaceships, x_pos)
        for s,x in comb:
            score = FONT.render(
                    "Score: {}".format(s.score),
                    False,
                    (255, 255, 255))

            screen.blit(score, (x, 70))
```

Comment: I assume you are using `pygame`. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The answer is yes, but it is quite painful and somewhat slow.

Comment: yes, im using pygame, and would like to learn both ways.. How can I return without?

Comment: The alternative way is to use `pygame.surfarray` and manually copy the values from one array to the other. But that is not really a good idea. Why do you want to do that?